# Why is active sec-pentyl group called so?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, terminology, hydrocarbons

My teacher as well as [Wikipedia — Pentyl group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentyl_group) use the following names for the “pentyl” groups:

|  | Group name | Structure with attachment point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | active *sec*-pentyl | [image: active sec-pentyl] |
| **2** | *sec*-pentyl | [image: sec-pentyl] |
| **3** | active pentyl | [image: active pentyl] |

If a group is attached to the second carbon of pentyl, then it is called “active *sec*-pentyl” (**1**). If it is attached to the third carbon, then it is called “*sec*-pentyl” (**2**). In case **3** it is called “active pentyl”.

What is the difference between them, and why are they called so?

Comment: Where are these terms from?

Comment: @orthocresol Really, you never heard these!! Am I reading wrong things, because when I search sec pentyl chloride on google, i get results. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/03%3A_Organic_Compounds-_Alkanes_and_Their_Stereochemistry/3.03%3A_Alkyl_Groups here it says we have sec butyl but sec pentyl doesn't exist, but i didn't got reason. And i have read these names as common names. I am literally confused.

Comment: Oh, sec-pentyl is fine, even if uncommon (the usefulness of the sec- prefix probably stops at butyl, because for pentyl onwards there are plenty of possible isomeric candidates which can lay claim to the 'sec' description). But *'active'*, that's a new one.

Comment: @orthocresol [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentyl_group?wprov=sfla1) considers sec-pentyl as 1-methylbutyl and active pentyl as 2-methylbutyl. Are they referring to "active" as in optically active?

Comment: @NilayGhosh I see the answer has taken a similar approach at least...

Comment: Active! the word optically is omitted like oxide is omitted from carbon. sec-butanol from fermentation fusel oils is usually optically active whence the term active. #2 is definitely ambiguous. It is best that these names be used with care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I, as orthocresol♦ questioned in the comments section, don't know where these terms came from. Thus, any attempt to rationalize these terms would be a speculation. For clarity, it could be argued that each of the structures of these alkyl radicals are drawn in such a way that each of them is attached to a functional group such as hydroxyl or halide or etc. For sake of an argument, let's assume the functional group is hydroxyl, thus the compound from the first radical would be 2-pentanol (or pent-2-ol). Thus, let's try to give a meaningful rationalization to the terminology in the question:

1. Why it is called 'active sec pentyl' (case 1): If you carefully look at the alkyl radical in case 1, you would realize it is a secondary radical so that it is a *sec*-pentyl group. Thus, the compound is **optically active** alcohol (in our case), pent-2-ol, which can exists in both (*R*)- and (*S*)-forms. Thus, I assume 'active' part comes to indicate optically active compounds.
2. Why it is called 'sec pentyl' (case 2): If you carefully look at the alkyl radical in case 2, you would realize it is also a secondary radical so that it is also a *sec*-pentyl group. Thus, the relevant compound in our case is pent-3-ol, which can exists in only one form, because it is **not optically active**. Thus, I assume 'active' part is dropped from 'active sec pentyl' to indicate the radical forms only the non-optically active compounds, yet it is a 'sec pentyl'.

The compound related to 'case 3' is 3-methylbutan-1-ol, which is  **optically active** so that it has been given the terminology, 'active pentyl'.